# How to initialize BluetoothDevice object with known mac address in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to initialize `BluetoothDevice` object with known mac address but, I do not know how to initialize.

Please guide me how to initialize the below object with the mac address 00:11:22:33:44, I would be very thankful for your kind response.

```
BluetoothDevice device;
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lets assume that
String address = "00:11:22:33:44";

```
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
        (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
```